# Keep getting CORS error when calling the API from cloud Functions in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am constantly getting cors error when calling the Api. I have tried different methods to fix the problem but nothing seems to work. The code works just fine when I call the Api in my local environment with the emulators working, the problem appears when I try to call the live api. I have tried literally everything, from adding headers in the firebase.json to using the cors module or specifying the origin domains. I even have permissions in the Firebase console set to allUsers but I am still getting cors error, what is the error?

This how the cloud function looks like:

```js
exports.getAccessToken = onRequest(
  { cors: true },
  (request, response) => {
    response.json({ client: 'test' });
  }
);
```

And this is how I am calling the api:

```js
let test = FirebaseUtils.getAccessToken(code).then(test => console.log(test));
```

```js
static getAccessToken = async (code) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${this.apiUrl('getAccessToken')}?code=${code}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Fortnox token:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Didi you try with the CF deployed on the Firebase/Google Cloud backend?

Comment: Yes. I deployed the functions on the cloud, that's when the error started to appear

Comment: What specific error are you getting back in the browser console for the CORS error? What error code/reason is it providing? What happens when you access the target URL directly in your browser? (edit these details into your question)

Comment: I solved it :). Looks like it was some kind of cache from firebase. I deleted the function itself from firebase and deployed again then everything worked just fine! Thank You anyway, appreciate the help :)